# Find moment of inertia for cylindrical segment

Tags: geometry

I want to find the moment of inertia for a cylindrical segment.

For the volume, I have found that the integral is as follows. Let

$$h(r,\theta) = h_1 +\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{r}{R}\cos(\theta) \right) (h_2-h_1)$$

Then
$$V =\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{h(r,\theta)}rdzd\theta dr$$

My source is [here][1].

(Note they have typo in the order of integration)

However, I've recently been calculating a lot of moments of inertia and I almost always need to integrate $z$ from $-\frac{h}{2}$ to $\frac{h}{2}$. So I'm concerned the limits of integration here would not work for the moment of inertia.

Would the bounds for this integral be suitable for calculating the moment of inertia? If not, how would I do it?

---

EDIT:

I think I can show easily this integral is not correct. If this integral were correct, we could set $h_1 = h_2 = h$. When we do this, $h(r,\theta) = h$. Then the integral becomes

$$\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{h}\begin{bmatrix}
y^2 + z^2 & -xy & -xz\\
-yx & x^2 + z^2 & -yz\\
-zx & -zy & x^2 + y^2 \\
\end{bmatrix} r dzd\theta dr$$

If you do this, you get
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{12} m \left(4 h^2+3 R^2\right) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{12} m \left(4 h^2+3 R^2\right) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{m R^2}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which does not equal the moment of inertia tensor of a cylinder, which you can find here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia

However, if you do

$$\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{h(r,\theta)}{2}}^{\frac{h(r,\theta)}{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
y^2 + z^2 & -xy & -xz\\
-yx & x^2 + z^2 & -yz\\
-zx & -zy & x^2 + y^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}rdzd\theta dr$$

Then in the simple case of $h_1 = h_2 = h$,

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{12} m \left(h^2+3 R^2\right) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{12} m \left(h^2+3 R^2\right) & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{m R^2}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

However, I'm not sure if this special case is sufficient to show that it works.
[1]: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalSegment.html

Answer (score 2):

If the volume is given by $$V =\int_0^R \left( \int_0^{2\pi}r \left(\int_{0}^{h(r,\theta)}\,{\rm d}z\right){\rm d}\theta \right){\rm d}r$$

then the mass moment of inertia (tensor) about the origin is

$$\mathbf{I} = \rho\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} r \int_{0}^{h(r,\theta)}
\begin{vmatrix} y^2+z^2 & -x y & -x z \\ -x y & x^2+z^2 & -y z \\ -x z & -y z & x^2+y^2 \end{vmatrix}
\,{\rm d}z\,{\rm d}\theta\,{\rm d}r$$

where $\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = \mathrm{pos}(r,\,\theta,\,z)$ is the parameterization of the position of each element ${\rm d}V$, and the density is $\rho = m/V$.

I think you want $x=r \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$, but depending on your coordinates, it might be something different but similar.

Comment: Wait, the order you are integrating the variables doesn't match Wolfram's website. Their order is the one I posted with $r$ first.  To be honest however, urs makes a lot more sense. Do you think they have a typo on their site?

Comment: Its the same, as long as the $r$ is multiplied before the $\int {\rm d}\theta$. For clarity I moved the $r$ factor into the integral, instead of the differential element. The result is the same, and WA website correlates with my answer.